# Wrong match with LIKE and parameter

Tags: sql-server, sqlparameter

I want to compare a string to see if it contains a substring, however, when I use a variable it evaluates to true when it should be false.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

```
DECLARE @Match VARCHAR
SET @Match = '%Matching%'

SELECT CASE WHEN 'Does This Match' LIKE @Match THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Does This Match' LIKE '%Matching%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a silly issue.  If you declare something as `VARCHAR` in a `CAST` then it auto-sizes the VARCHAR <del>properly</del> to `VARCHAR(30)`.  In this case, though, you have a single VARCHAR character.  So when you set it to `%Matching%` because `@Match` is only ONE character long, `@Match` gets set to just the wildcard character `%` which DOES match that phrase (and any phrase!).

`DECLARE @Match VARCHAR(50)`

Do that, then works.

Full example:

```
DECLARE @BadMatch VARCHAR
SET @BadMatch = '%Matching%'


DECLARE @Match VARCHAR(20)
SET @Match = '%Matching%'

SELECT @BadMatch, @Match

SELECT CASE WHEN 'Does This Match' LIKE @Match THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Does This Match' LIKE '%Matching%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- 0
```

Comment: It doesn't "autosize" it if no length is specified in a cast. It uses `VARCHAR(30)` rather than `varchar(1)` though.

Comment: @MartinSmith the default value is 1 for the (n)char and (n)varchar data types when they are used in variable declaration

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Yes I know. The point I was correcting was the sentence `If you declare something as VARCHAR in a CAST then it auto-sizes the VARCHAR properly`. This is not the case. `CAST(X AS VARCHAR)` will cause an error or truncation if `X` is longer than 30 characters.

Comment: +1 I thought it auto-sized and did NOT know it defaulted to 30.  I always wondered how it calculated the size :)  Fixing my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

varchar will not work because that would be equivalent to varchar(1) one character wide.
Use varchar(SIZE)